# Why won't Ubuntu use the memory I have left on my PC?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I recently installed Ubuntu on my PC. When I tried installing a Valve game on Ubuntu, it said that I only have 2000 megabytes of memory left on my PC.

When I switched back to Windows 7, it said that I have another 500 gigabytes of memory left.

I would really appreciate it if someone could find me an answer to this problem.

Comment: Do you mean memory as in RAM or disc space?

Comment: disk space = "storage", not memory.

Answer (score 0):

Likely because Ubuntu and Windows are each in their own partition. Your Windows partition has 500GB free, your Linux partition has 2GB free. If you want more space on your Linux partition then you are going to need to shrink down your Windows partition using a partition manager like gparted and reassign that space to your Linux partition.